# Securing Dash App with Flask's @login_required

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

Can someone help me protect my Dash path by using Flask?

This is how I call my dashboard

```
def my_dashboard(flask_app):
    app = Dash(__name__, server=flask_app, url_base_pathname="/Mandant/")

    app.title = "Dashboard"
```

My main Flask app

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "123" 

login_manager = LoginManager(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return load_user_from_yaml(user_id)


kraftfahrt_sachgebiet(app)  # Dashboard Function Call
```

Many thanks in advance.

I have tried the following code but it is not working.

```
def protect_views(app):
    for view_func in app.server.view_functions:
        if view_func.startswith(app.url_base_pathname):
            app.server.view_functions[view_func] = login_required(app.server.view_functions[view_func])

    return app
```